# how to get response from AWS S3 uploader

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, model-view-controller, amazon-s3

i am using AWS S3 to store files.
i am able to upload and delete files.
only problem is while uploading large file, how to know how much uploaded AND I need implement like progress bar.

please help me to do that.

```
 IAmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(RegionEndpoint.USEast2);
            TransferUtility utility = new TransferUtility(client);
            TransferUtilityUploadRequest request = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest();
if (subDirectoryInBucket == "" || subDirectoryInBucket == null)
            {
                request.BucketName = bucketName; //no subdirectory just bucket name  
            }
            else
            {   // subdirectory and bucket name  
                request.BucketName = bucketName + @"/" + subDirectoryInBucket;
            }
            request.Key = RandomString()+ Path.GetExtension(e.File.FileName); //file name up in S3  
            request.InputStream = e.File.InputStream;
            request.CannedACL=S3CannedACL.PublicRead;
            utility.Upload(request); //commensing the transfer
```

this code i am using .

Answer (score 0):

Hi there method call TransferUtilityUploadRequest you can use that,

below is the example you can also refer this [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HLTrackProgressMPUDotNet.html)!    hope this helps

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Configuration;
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Transfer;


namespace s3.amazon.com.docsamples
{
    class TrackMPUUsingHighLevelAPI
    {
        static string existingBucketName = "*** Provide bucket name ***";
        static string keyName            = "*** Provide key name ***";
        static string filePath           = "*** Provide file to upload ***";

    static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        try
        {
            TransferUtility fileTransferUtility =
                new TransferUtility(new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1));

            // Use TransferUtilityUploadRequest to configure options.
            // In this example we subscribe to an event.
            TransferUtilityUploadRequest uploadRequest =
                new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
                {
                    BucketName = existingBucketName,
                    FilePath = filePath, 
                    Key = keyName
                };

            uploadRequest.UploadProgressEvent +=
                new EventHandler<UploadProgressArgs>
                    (uploadRequest_UploadPartProgressEvent);

            fileTransferUtility.Upload(uploadRequest);
            Console.WriteLine("Upload completed");
        }

        catch (AmazonS3Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message, e.InnerException);
        }
    }

    static void uploadRequest_UploadPartProgressEvent(
        object sender, UploadProgressArgs e)
    {
        // Process event.
        Console.WriteLine("{0}/{1}", e.TransferredBytes, e.TotalBytes);
    }
}
}
```